# What board should I use to control my 3D printer

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, hardware

I'm trying to build a simple experimental FDM 3D printer as a hobby.
As I said it's a simple printer with only basic functionalities such as receiving the slicer file to print from a slicer software from PC and sending back the print status to the PC.

Following are other functionality of the printer:.

1. Sends the X and Y coordinates of the printhead and Z cordinate of print platform to the PC.
2. Sends the temperature of the cartridge heater to the PC with the help of a temperature probe.
3. Send the number of layers printed  currently.

Now in order to achieve the above mentioned functionality and control the printer via the PC, what microcontroller motherboard is ideal to use? Is using Arduino Uno ideal enough? Or should I use Arduino Mega or any Rasbery Pi board.

Comment: I would be very surprised if you manage to get a 3D printer work directly from an STL file without slicing it first (to create G code). That is not "basic".

Comment: @StarCat you are right I first need to send the stl file to a slicer software and the software should send data to the printer. I've edited the question.

Comment: A few months ago, I were in the same stage than you are now, I wanted to build a 3D printer as hobby. Since then, I've learned a lot about this. There are a lot of previous solutions for all those questions that you presented, there is REPRAP, an open-source solution. Even if you build your own frames and platform, there's no need to reinvent the whell when doing the electronic control of a 3D printer. The key to the electronic control is Arduino + RAMPS. Google for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything different in your application to any of the 3D extruder-based printer applications. All this has been sorted out many, many times already.

[image]

Most use an Arduino-based board with built-in stepper drivers and temperature control interface. [Marlin](https://marlinfw.org/) firmware, for example, allows monitoring of position and temperature on the printer's LCD so that you don't have to leave the laptop connected - although you can if you want to.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8tUjf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The slicer software doesn't generate a "slicer file", it generates CNC g-code which can be transferred by SD card to the printer which reads and executes line by line. Most slicer software can drive the printer over USB or Ethernet but that ties up the laptop for the duration of the print.

Comment: Do printers from popular brands such as MakerBot, Ultimaker, Stratasys etc all use Arduino boards and Marlin firmware?

Comment: No, they don't all use Arduino boards and Marlin firmware.

Comment: @Somanna: They don't all use Arduino boards and Marlin firmware, because they're commercial products. If you are just starting with 3D printing, **and you intend to build your own printer**, there is no reason for not using Arduino + RAMPS + Marlin. If you have the skills enough to create a different solution, you would not be here asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

*Now in order to achieve the above mentioned functionality and control the printer via the PC, what microcontroller motherboard is ideal to use? 
Is using Arduino Uno ideal enough? Or should I use Arduino Mega or any Rasbery Pi board.*

Even a simple 3D printer has about twenty or thirty different wires connected (see picture below). This is so much for Arduino Uno.

The "universal standard" solution for electronic control of 3D printing is an Arduino Mega with a "RAMPS" add-on board.

You could use other microcontroller, you could use other firmware than Marlin, you could use a new and self-built custom solution for all of the hardware and software parts.

But, if you are a newbie in this arena, **there is no reason for don't go with the mainstream.**

Read some books, and do some Google work; search for "RAMPS", search for "DIY REPRAP".

https://reprap.org/wiki/Build_A_RepRap

[image]